# Alternative method to count number of single occurencies across columns of interest

Tags: r, for-loop, count, iteration

I would like the number of single occurrences of some rows values across different columns. I have applied the following code:

```
dat = data.frame()
vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
for (i in names(data)){
  for (j in vector){
    dat[j,i] <- length(which(data[,i] == j))
  }
}

print(dat)
```

That return exactly the output I am looking for. Does this code contain any redundancies? Could you please some more effective **alternative way with the iterative method (including for loop)** or with **dplyr() packages**?

Thanks

Here is a short extract of the dataset I am working on.

```
structure(list(run_set_1 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), run_set_2 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), run_set_3 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first `match()` each column to get the index in `vector` that
the column values correspond to, if any. Then `tabulate()` those to get the
counts, including 0s:

```r
lapply(data, match, vector) |>
  sapply(tabulate, length(vector))
#>      run_set_1 run_set_2 run_set_3
#> [1,]         0         6         0
#> [2,]         0         0         6
#> [3,]         6         0         0
```

This can be modified to use `dplyr`-native iteration:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

data %>% 
  summarise(
    across(everything(), match, vector) %>%
      purrr::map_dfc(tabulate, length(vector))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   run_set_1 run_set_2 run_set_3
#>       <int>     <int>     <int>
#> 1         0         6         0
#> 2         0         0         6
#> 3         6         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice chunk of code. Do you mind please to explain what the `|>` does exaclty?

Comment: It's called the "forward pipe operator", and it passes the expression on the left hand side as the first argument to the call on the right hand side. Here it's equivalent to writing `sapply(lapply(...), ...)`, but without nesting function calls. For more, see `?"|>"`.

Comment: You could also use a helper function (anonymous or not) to combine the two iteration steps into one. An alternative (slower) way to do the counting would be `\(x) table(factor(x, vector))`.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive comments. I am moving my very first steps with R and I am always enthusiastic when I can learn from someone who is more grounded than me. Thanks, I'll try to thìo think about this and in case I'll text some doubts here

Comment: Actually, I was just wondering whether the code I've texted is too extended. Maybe there might be some more shortened ways to get to some results with for loops

Comment: @creativity the only straightforward simplification to your original loop approach that I can think of would be to use `sum(...)` instead of `length(which(...))` -- although then the behaviour would be a bit different in the presence of missing values.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : I added the case for a value that we expect but is missing (4 as example)

Here is the `tidyverse` version. I think it may be even shorter but I don't know yet.

```
vector = c(1:4)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    mutate(value = factor(as.character(value), levels = vector)) %>%
    count(name, value, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n) %>%
    arrange(value) %>% select(-value)
# last line only to remove the value column and fit your example

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   run_set_1 run_set_2 run_set_3
#       <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1         0         6         0
# 2         0         0         6
# 3         6         0         0
# 4         0         0         0
```

Comment: Very nice. I was looking at how to get the same be dplyr() package but I ended up getting the counting for gruìouped columns. Impressive!!

Comment: Yeah, finding how to group is the main thing to understand with the tidyverse way. Here it's simple since you only have two column, group by them and it's done ^^

I'm not happy that it takes so many lines but half of them are to pivot the data to fit tidyverse and rbase formats so I guess it can't be any shorter.

Comment: I noticed you don't use `vector` at all -- this wouldn't produce the correct result if there are values in `vector` that don't appear in any of the columns in `data`. I thought at some point `dplyr` added a way to return results for all levels of a grouping factor (so you could do `value = factor(value, vector)`), but I can't remember how, now.

Comment: You are right, after reading your edit, it works way better ! I edited mine to fit this case of missing data

Comment: @Gowachin ahh I see it was `.drop` in `group_by()`/`count()`. I totally glazed over that! Thanks!